# Не работает отладка Visual Studoi Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Написал код питон, нажал F5 - не сработало. Создал новый файл, написал print('hello') - так же не работает, помогите пожалуйста[text](https://vk.com/video288489427_456239169) https://vk.com/video288489427_456239169
Ошибок нет никаких, ничего не происходит

Comment: Не хватает репы, чтобы оставить комментарий, напишу здесь. Ознакомся с правилами формулирования вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
Что касается самого вопроса, попробуй погуглить debugging in vscode(вот, например: https://lightrun.com/debug-python-in-vscode/), там детально описывается алгоритм. Больше тебе ничем не могу помочь, нехватает данных

Comment: Во-первых, ваша ссылка не открывается ("Автор ограничил доступ к видео").
Во-вторых, весь необходимый код, текст ошибок и прочую информацию следует указывать в самом вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно произошла похожая ситуация. Решил ее чистой переустановкой по этому гайду https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0CiiyevSZM. Также на аккаунте, который синхронизировал, все настройки заменил на стандартные.
Еще я потестил. Если расширение python debugger не установлено, то симптомы проблемы такие же. Вероятно, проблема была изначально в этом :D

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)